# Easier Way to Format Excel Data For SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

I often receive requests to query a SQL Server database based on data that is sent to me in an Excel spreadsheet.

I am looking for a more efficient way of completing these types of requests than my current setup:

Currently in order to complete the request I do the following:

Copy the Excel column containing the data that will eventually be placed in a WHERE clause.

Paste the data as text only into Microsoft Word.

Do a find for each paragraph marker and replace it with ', '

Then surround the entire clause with parenthesis to enter into an IN clause.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a more efficient way of accomplishing the same task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

**Query the excel spreadsheet directly**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\excelfile.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

**Use excel to format the data**:

In next empty column `= A1 & ","`  then copy-down, or `="'"&A1&"',"`

Comment: i was just editiing to suggest query the sheet but you got there before me :P

Comment: Your second suggestion is a great option. Once I have each cell formatted properly, is there a way to concatenate all of the cells in that column?

Comment: You can `transpose` them, you can use `=TRANSPOSE()` with the range, or you can copy all the cells and then right-click an empty cell and there's a transpose paste option, the icon is a couple horizontal boxes next to a couple vertical boxes.  The latter method is only in newer versions, can't remember when they added it.

Comment: That doesn't put them into one cell, but they'll paste nicely that way.

Comment: Great! I thought that because the transpose option still keeps each item in a separate cell that this would not work, however it copies over to SQL great. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

You could save the excell as a CSV comma delimited file and go from there but if this is a regular thing i would probably set up an SSIS process to do it all for you